# How to merge multiple files based on a timestamp

Tags: shell-script, awk, cat, paste

I have 2 files

File 1:

```
01:12:00,001 Some text

01:14:00,003 Some text

02:12:01,394 Some text
```

File 2:

```
01:12:00,001 Some text

01:12:01,029 Some text

01:13:21,123 Some text
```

I need output as follows:

```
01:12:00,001 Some text

01:12:00,001 Some text

01:12:01,029 Some text

01:13:21,123 Some text

01:14:00,003 Some text

02:12:01,394 Some text
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're asking for the file to be sorted by the order that the fields appear in the file, this is the most basic use of `sort`:

```
sort file1 file2 > outputfile
```

Answer (score 6):

If the original files are already in time-stamp order, it will probably be fastest to use the merge option in `sort`.

```
sort -m file1 file2 > outputfile
```

From `man sort`:

```
   -m, --merge
          merge already sorted files; do not sort
```